# Does "prime" also mean spring?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot

According to dictionaries (available to me), *prime* means *premium, prime, bonus*, etc, and *printemps* means *spring*. But I have seen that *prime* is also translated into *spring* in French. So I wonder if *prime* also means *spring* in French.

Comment: Can you provide a reference about *prime* being translated to *spring*?

Comment: In the Nostradamus quatrain 9.48, "Dans le solstice hyemal et la prime..." is translated as "In the winter solstice and the spring...".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not anymore. *Prime* is an archaic way to say *premier/première* (first) still used in fixed expression like *de prime abord* (at first glance).

*La prime* meant "the first one" or "the beginning of" and when referring to a season was indeed used in old French to mean the beginning of spring (along with *primver*), or the beginning of the year. Occitan, Catalan, Spanish, and Italian all use *primavera* to express spring, with *ver* meaning spring in Latin. French still has *primevère* but only for the flower (primrose). *Prime* and *primver* were competing with and have been superseded by *printemps*, from Latin *primus tempus*: the first time.

Answer (score 2):

En complément à une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/45326), bien c'est doublement intéressant parce que [*prime*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/prime) « est la forme féminine (1119) de l'ancien adjectif *prim*, avec nasalisation *prin*, surtout employé dans des locutions (*primesaut*), outre quelques composés (*primerose, primevère, printemps*) » (*Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sup. A. Rey, *le Robert*, 2010). Donc le *prin* de printemps, c'est *prime*.

Ensuite on trouve au Godefroy *prime* signifiant *printemps* comme tel : « Dieu fet sans fin les nuits apres les jours : l'hyver apres l'automne, apres l'hyver la prime » ([Du Bartas](https://micmap.org/dicfro/page/dictionnaire-godefroy/405/6/prime)). On trouve aussi dans les citations sur l'adjectif *prin* : « Signeur, ce fu en mai que florissent gardin. Oisillon s'esjoissent contre le doux tamps prin » ([Druet Vignon](https://micmap.org/dicfro/next/dictionnaire-godefroy/407/6/prim)).

Si comme on l'a dit ailleurs on n'emploie plus aujourd'hui *prime* pour ce printemps comme on le faisait il y 500 ans, on l'utilise néanmoins à chaque fois en composé dans *printemps*...

Comment: Un exemple précurseur du verlan, ce ***tamps prin*** ! ;-)